# Auto running Textview (SingleLine marquee)

Tags: android, marquee

Im trying to get this effect : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4uAA4pik68

but somehow my Textview is kinda buggy and doesnt look like this in the video.
This following code is making the infinite rotation animation very messed up.

It looks like it just start from the beginning when its finished (weird to explain).So there is no smooth animation like in the video.Its very cuty and looks like it jumps from end to start.

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"

            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Title"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/textView_title_full"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to programmatically set the selected property of the `TextView` -

```
    TextView textView_title_full = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_title_full);
    textView_title_full.setSelected(true);
```

Comment: I didn't. It was someone else but I allready done that without success mate. Some other ideas ?